# Find Out The Running Time Of A Recursive Algorithm (Master-Therorem)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion, master-theorem

Here is the algorithm whose running time I want to calculate:

```
T(n) = {
        c0 * n, if n <= 20
        T(roundUp(n/4)) + T(roundUp(5/12 * n + 3/2)) + c1*n, if n > 20
       }
```

n is part of the positive natural numbers, c0 and c1 are constants.

Here is the algorithm in java-code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 20; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " :    " + rec(i, 1, 1));
        }
    }

    public static int rec(int n, int c0, int c1) {
        int res = 0;
        if (n <= 20) {
            res += c0 * n;
        } else {
            double temp = n / 4d;
            double temp2 = n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d);
            res += rec((int) Math.ceil(temp), c0, c1) + rec((int) Math.ceil(temp2), c0, c1) + c1 * n;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I'm looking for an approach or an explaining example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, didn't do this for long time, but since nobody gave answer yet, let me try. You basically create tree here, with two important children. Left one is based on `temp = n / 4d`, and right one is based on `temp2 = n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d)`. So question is, how deep is this tree? Since `n / 4d` will end up under `20` quicker then `n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d)` we care only about right child. So question is, how much far right children are there based on `n`? 
As we iterate, we have this:

```
n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d) 
ceil(n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d) ) * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d)
ceil(ceil(n * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d)) * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d) ) * (5 / 12d) + (3 / 2d)
...
```

Here, we can also ignore `3/2d` part, as well as everything related to it, so we get this:

```
n * (5 / 12) ^ k < 20
```

Where `k` is the number of steps to reach most far right child, so we have:

```
n * (5 / 12) ^ k < 20
k = log_(5 / 12) (20 / n)
k = log_2(20 / n) / log_2 (5 / 12)   
k = (log_2 (20) - log_2(n) ) / log_2 (5 / 12)
```

Since this:

```
k = log_2 (20) / log_2 (5 / 12)
```

is a specific number, we can ignore it...

```
k = - log_2(n) / log_2 (5 / 12)
```

Since:

```
log_2 (5 / 12)  < 0
```

we are left with:

```
k = log_2(n) = lgn
```

As expected, since we work only with tree, you get `O(n) = lg(n)`.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Thank you very much.
Can you tell me how I can write the the running time like this:
T(n) ∈ Θ(f(n))

So I`m looking for the correct f(n)

Comment: Its k without removing fixed values: T(n) = log_2 (20) / log_2 (5 / 12) + log_2(n) / log_2 (12 / 5) , and f(n) is lg(n) or log_2(n)

Comment: yes it is. See more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation under Infinite asymptotics What I did in order to get Θ(log_2(n)) is I reduced T(n) to lead value. Since T(n) is quite "stable", you can use O(log_2(n)) rather then Θ(log_2(n)).